# How do i get these values to save?

Tags: java, android

I need the inserted values in this edittext to show up after i quit the application. I currently have it set up so it'll set new default values if this is the first time for a user to set up the settings page but i can't get the set values to save and load the same values. Here is my code.

```
            if (res.equals("555")) {
            //post the saved text
        } else if (res.equals("510")) {
            editTextname.setText("Firstname Lastname", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            editTextphone.setText("XXX-XXX-XXXX", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            editTextemail.setText("name@yourdomain.com", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            editTextaddress.setText("Street, City, State, Zip", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            //save the entered text above and show it
        }
```

Comment: -1 for tagging with php and mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPreference", MODE_PRIVATE);

// On first run:
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
if(!prefs.contains("key1"))
    editor.putString("key1", "defaultValue1");
if(!prefs.contains("key2"))
    editor.putString("key2", "defaultValue2");
editor.commit();

// On save:
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("key1", "value1");
editor.putString("key2", "value3");
editor.commit();

// On read:
String value1 = prefs.getString("key1");
String value2 = prefs.getString("key2");
```

Comment: just have a SharedPreferences.Editor write the values and have a SharedPreferences object check for/open them on the app launch

Comment: i tried, could you give me a nice layout? @Kevin Qiu the application im making needs it specifically to only happen after initial launch so it is pretty impossible.

Comment: are there any other methods i can use to save the text entered inside edittext boxes?

Comment: You have two choices for saving persistant data: SharedPreferences or a file (or database which is a file), either works but the shared preferences are probably easier and faster to implement.

Comment: what do you mean it can only happen after initial launch? then delete the info after you don't need it anymore.

Comment: thank you, what is the on first run for exactly? do i put it on the first activity created by the application or the activity that uses the specific information?

Comment: The first run part writes the default values, remove that part if you don't want that.

Comment: I think Drake pointing when the data has been saved or loaded, right?
you load data on first init, `onResume` / `onCreate` will do... For saving the data to SharedPReferences, I think you can put it on `onPause` / `onStop`.. to make sure the value saved when the app is closed..